# itertools cominbations with replacement with limitations

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there a better way to list all the possible combinations with replacement with a minimum and maximum occurrence for each of the elements than to (1) list all the possible combinations without these restrictions with `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` and then (2) check the result one by one to see if they meet the restrictions?

As an example, say if I have an array `[a b c]` that I want to draw from for 10 times, but I want to see each of the elements for at least 1 time but no more than half the time (i.e. 5 times), I don't want to see the following

```
b b b b b c c c c c # no a
a a a a a a b b c c # a more than 5 times
```

my real array is bigger with 20 elements to draw 100 times from...

thanks in advance

edit:

here's what I have tried, but obviously it doesn't seem efficient with my 20 elements being drawn 100 times...

```
a = []
for c in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(4), 10)):
    valid = 1
    for i in range(4):
        if not c.count(i) or c.count(i) > 5:
            valid = 0
            break
    if valid:
        a.append(c)
```

what I am really trying to do is that I have 20 items, and I want to figure out all the possible basket that I can generate from them, with proportion in incremental integer (i.e. 1%, 2%, etc, no 1.5%), hence 100 times to add up to 100%. each item should always appear but none of them should be more than 50%...

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Easier to program? I doubt it. Marginally more efficient? Sure, I expect so. More efficient enough to justify the time it'd take to verify you've gotten it right? Not so clear. As a puzzle, this may be worth spending time on. In terms of clean reasonable programming, I'd bet the straightforward, inelegant solution you articulate is a good choice.

Comment: It's easy enough to take the first step of getting some of your minimum requirements: just say that instead of 10 draws with each of a,b,c to appear at least once, you want 7 draws from a,b,c, and then consider the interleavings of those results with a stipulated draw of each of a,b,c in every order that can occur. (Some of these interleavings will be equivalent to each other, you'd have to work around that.) That could potentially be a bit more efficient, but I wouldn't be shocked to learn that the overhead eats away the gains.

Comment: Make sure the number of combinations you want to iterate over is actually reasonable. It probably isn't, in which case you'll have to use a less brute-force solution to the problem underlying this one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj added my attempt

Comment: @user2357112 added exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion based on the approach you posted:

**See all elements at least once:** You could start with the results array populated with a set of your elements.

Starting with such a "seed" somewhat limits the number of combinations to check and eliminate for duplicates; it also simplifies the checking.

```
import itertools
a = []
seed = (0,1,2,3)
for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(4), 6):
    valid = True
    for i in range(4):
        if c.count(i) > 4:
            valid = False
            break
    if valid:
        a.append(c+seed)
a
```

You can create a generator expression (based on the same principle):

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
a = ((0,1,2,3) + c for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(4), 6) if max(Counter(c).values()) < 5)
```

Comment: Your solution to #2 is going to produce lots and lots of duplicate combinations.

Comment: Yes, of course, there are "lots and lots" of similar combinations in the present case.  The OP did not require the draws to be distinct.

Comment: The question is to list all combinations, not to draw random ones. Also, even for drawing random combinations, this is going to produce a highly skewed output distribution.

Comment: You are correct; I modified the approach. The skewed distribution is part of the requirements (it seems), but can be filtered out for the size of array mentioned.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque : thanks for your answer. let me digest this a bit first. but i have also updated my question with more background. thanks!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: agreed your step 6 seems to address the must-always-appear criteria. but if I do a combinations of 6 elements I will likely end up with some elements appearing more than 3 times (so total more than 4 repeats)...

Comment: I posted an approach similar to yours, but with a starting seed consisting of a set of the elements - there are some combinatorics advantages to this, and a bit of saving on the checking tests.

Comment: 1.) the generator is not optional, the little less than 20^100 items are not going to fit into a list on any system (see `sys.maxsize`), but 2.) if you want to iterate over `a` such as `len(a)` then this is still an `O(n^m)` algorithm - on my system calculating len(a) for 10^4 items took 0.1s, 10^5 - 1s and 10^6 - 10 seconds, so would take more than the age of the universe to calculate len(a) of 10^23 combinations...

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the actual requirement suggests an immediate, efficient, and simple (though inelegant) solution.

First imagine that you don't have the less than 50 requirement:

Simply use 19 nested for loops.  The outside one loops from 1 to 81, the next one from 1 to 82 subtract the first one, and so on.  The last number then fills up to 100.

To add the less than 50% requirement you need to make the loops stop at 50 if that is less than the number calculated above.  They also need to start higher if the final number would otherwise be larger than 50.

This will be very efficient and direct - it will generate only the ones you want.  It can be re-written to use a variable number instead of a fixed 20 though that makes it rather complex.

However, the point of user2357112 is well made, and emphasised by this simple formulation.  A rough estimate of the number of combinations here is significantly larger than 2e13.  It is unlikely this sort of brute force approach is going to work.  You probably need a more sophisticated approach to the underlying problem.

Comment: Ahh - missed the less than 50% requirement - edit needed.

Comment: that's an interesting idea... I wonder if I can make a recursive function to do that...

Comment: Yes I think it's not too hard.  But bear in mind, as I say, that the run will not finish in a reasonable time.  In fact, I think, it won't finish in your lifetime.